# How to pass arguments to nested navigation graph with deep link Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-deep-link

I have a nested navigation graph that takes arguments, with a Timer Screen as a child, and I'm attempting to deep link to the Timer screen from a notification.  When I do that, the nested navigation graph is created, as expected, but since it takes arguments, those arguments don't exist when navigating to my_app://timer, and the app crashes.

How can I navigate to a nested navigation destination whose parent takes arguments?

I have a navigation graph defined as follows:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.bookDetailNavigationFlow(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = NavigationScreens.BOOK_DETAIL,
        route = "${NavigationScreens.BOOK_DETAIL_FLOW}?id={id}&bookType={bookType}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("id") { type = NavType.StringType },
            navArgument("bookType") { type = NavType.StringType }
        )
    ) {
        val bookType = BookType.fromNavString(
            navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString("bookType") ?: BookType.UserBookType.getNavString()
        )

        timerScreenDestination(navController)
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

and Timer Screen defined as follows:

```
composable(
    route = NavigationScreens.TIMER,
    deepLinks = listOf(
        navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "my_app://timer"
        }
    )
) {
    // Timer Screen
}
```

Pending intent:

```
val pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                "my_app://timer".toUri()
            )
        )
        getPendingIntent(2345, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }
```